# How to create an ArrayList of arrays of Objects in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I was wondering how exactly to create an `ArrayList` of an array of objects. For example

```
Object[] objectArray = new Object() // Varying amount of object[]
```

I would like to add `Object[]` to an `ArrayList` as they come in. I have seen that an `ArrayList` of arrays can be created by the following:

```
ArrayList<String[]> action = new ArrayList<String[]>();
```

So I was thinking it would be as simple as:

```
ArrayList<objectArray[]> action = new ArrayList<objectArray[]>();
```

But apparently not.

Answer (score 2):

You create an ArrayList of arrays this way :

```
ArrayList<Object[]> action = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
```

Each time you add an Object[] to that list, it must have a fixed length.
If you want variable length arrays inside the ArrayList, I suggest you use `ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>`.

Your syntax with `objectArray` is simply not valid Java syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The type parameter in the generic `List` class should be the class name and not the name of the variable that references the array:

```
ArrayList<Object[]> action = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
```

Two notes:

1. Try to avoid declaring types to the implementations. Declare `action` as a `List` (the interface):

   `List<Object[]> action = new ArrayList<Object[]>();`
2. It would make life a bit easier if you make the parameter another `List` instead of an array of `Object`s:

   `List<List<?>> action = new ArrayList<List<?>>();`

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList<LoadClass[]> sd = new ArrayList<LoadClass[]>();`

This works :)

Answer (score 0):

So, you have two questions:

```
Object[] objectArray = new Object() 
ArrayList<objectArray[]> action = new ArrayList<objectArray[]>();
```

Change it to:

```
int MAX_ARRAY = 3;
Object[] objectArray = new Object[MAX_ARRAY];

ArrayList<Object[]> action = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
```

Now you can add your objectArray to "action":

```
action.add(objectArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a easy stuff.

```
// Class Student with a attribute name
public class Student{
    String name;
    public Student(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Creating an ArrayList for Students
    ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();

    // Creating an Students Objects
    Student a1 = new Student("Name1");
    Student a2 = new Student("Name2");
    Student a3 = new Student("Name3");

    // Populating ArrayList<Student>
    students.add(a1);
    students.add(a2);
    students.add(a3);

    // For Each to sweeping all objects inside of this ArrayList
    for(Student student : students){
        System.out.println(student.getName());
    }
}
```

Enjoy!